# Debugging modifications of sys.path

Tags: python, path

Some library seems to modify my `sys.path`, although I don't want ìt to be changed.

How can I find the python code line which alters `sys.path`?

**Related**

- [Where does sys.path get replaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212466/where-does-sys-path-get-replaced/33212467)

Comment: You can first check `sys.path` then import module and check it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the first things imported is the `sitecustomize` and `usercustomize` modules; you could replace `sys.path` with a custom list implementation that records all changes being made.

First, find where to place a `usercustomize` or `sitecustomize` module; the [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) can tell you where to place the first:

```
python -m site --user-site
```

If that directory doesn't exist yet, create it and in it put a `usercustomize.py` with:

```
import sys

class VerboseSysPath(list):
    def croak(self, action, args):
        frame = sys._getframe(2)
        print('sys.path.{}{} from {}:{}'.format(
            action, args, frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_lineno))

    def insert(self, *args):
        self.croak('insert', args)
        return super().insert(*args)
    
    def append(self, *args):
        self.croak('append', args)
        return super().append(*args)

    def extend(self, *args):
        self.croak('extend', args)
        return super().extend(*args)

    def pop(self, *args):
        self.croak('pop', args)
        return super().pop(*args)

    def remove(self, *args):
        self.croak('remove', args)
        return super().remove(*args)

    def __delitem__(self, *args):
        self.croak('__delitem__', args)
        return super().__delitem__(*args)

    def __setitem__(self, *args):
        self.croak('__setitem__', args)
        return super().__setitem__(*args)

sys.path = VerboseSysPath(sys.path)
```

This now will complain about all attempts at altering the `sys.path` list.

Demo, with the above placed in either the `site-packages/sitecustomize.py` or `` `python -m site --user-site`/usercustomize.py `` modules:

```
$ cat test.py 
import sys

sys.path.append('')
$ bin/python test.py 
sys.path.append('',) from test.py:3
```

Comment: For anyone facing a similar problem: I couldn't trace the unexplained entries in `sys.path` by adding this code to `sitecustomize.py`, so i've ended up **temporarily** hacking this into `site.py` itself and managed to solve the problem (.pth file leftover from a  buggy installation). `site.py` is located in `lib` folder. Notably; if you're using a virtual environment, the core library does not come with, just `lib/site-packages`. You can find where your base installation is by looking at the first few entries in `sys.path`.

Comment: @MarcinKonowalczyk: Ah, yes, `.pth` files are processed before the `*customize` modules are imported. Note that `.pth` files in the per-user site-packages directory are loaded before those in the site directory, and any line that starts with `import` in such a file is executed, so you could use a `.pth` file instead of a `usercustomize` module to load the same `sys.path` instrumentation, and so not have to alter `site.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting python with `python -S` causes python not to load `site.py`, and so its default value is preserved from when python first starts up.