# Where does sys.path get replaced?

Tags: python, debugging, sys.path

Some library does change my `sys.path` in a way that I don't want it to.

But I can't find it. The affected virtualenv has a lot of libraries installed.

I replaced sys.path with a own class which alters the modifications, but this does not help, since the code seems to alter `sys.path` like this:

```
sys.path= [...] + sys.path
```

How can I find the "evil" code line and its stack trace?

**Related**

- [Debugging modifications of sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432910/debugging-modifications-of-sys-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the evil code line like this.

I alter sys.globals['sys'] in sitecustomize.py:

```
# sitecustomize.py
import sys

class AttributeIsReadonly(ValueError):
    pass

class MakeModuleAttributesReadonly(object):
    def __init__(self, module, readonly_attributes):
        self.module=module
        self.readonly_attributes=readonly_attributes

    def __setattr__(self, item, value):
        if item in ['module', 'readonly_attributes']:
            return super(MakeModuleAttributesReadonly, self).__setattr__(item, value)
        if item in self.readonly_attributes:
            raise AttributeIsReadonly('Access on attribute %r is readonly' % item)
        return setattr(self.module, item, value)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.module, item)

sys.modules['sys']=MakeModuleAttributesReadonly(sys, ['path'])

#import sys
#sys.path=sys.path # this will raise the above AttributeIsReadonly
```

It raises `AttributeIsReadonly` and I see the code line and the stack trace.

Comment: Why didn't you just add this as an alternative answer to the existing question?

Comment: Since in the current question sys.path does not get **modified**. It is a different question. It's related but not the same.

Comment: But surely having both answers in the same place would be more helpful for other users? Modification and replacement of the list are *technically* different, but you're solving the same underlying problem. Note that you could also have approached this by implementing `__add__` in `VerboseSysPath`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `__add__` won't work if the modification gets done like this `sys.path = [...] + sys.path`. But thank you for the feedback, I will update the question.

Comment: Yes, you'd need `__radd__` etc. as well. I still don't see this as different enough to justify a separate question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: having differently worded questions can be very helpful when searching for a problem.

Comment: @EthanFurman mainly if they're linked as duped to one canonical source of relevant information, though...