# Where is the connection between the two Python venv environments

Tags: python, linux, pytz, python-venv

I have two python environments and somehow there is some kind of link between them.

`/home/testapi/API25/env` is the original venv
`/home/preprodapi/API25/env` was created by means of a cpio copy from the first.  This worked find for many months.  But now a problem has cropped up.

The symptom is that in preprodapi the pytz package isnt able to find the timezone `Africa/Johannesburg` (and presumably others), as evidenced by the stack trace:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/preprodapi/API25.8512/validator/echo.py", line 244, in jsonified_wrapper
    response_obj = request_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/preprodapi/API25.8512/validator/echo.py", line 478, in bearer_token_wrapper
    return request_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/preprodapi/API25.8512/validator/echo.py", line 1068, in globaldb_connection_wrapper
    return request_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/preprodapi/API25.8512/validator/echo.py", line 569, in get_school_wrapper
    return request_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/preprodapi/API25.8512/validator/echo.py", line 697, in school_admin_wrapper
    return request_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/preprodapi/API25.8512/routehandlers.py", line 4035, in email_report
    do_email_report(kwargs.get('reportid'), json_attrs, getctx_school().get('schoolname'))
   File "/home/preprodapi/API25.8512/validator/echo.py", line 1155, in do_email_report
    tz = pytz.timezone(sender.school.get("local_timezone"))
   File "/home/testapi/API25/env/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 181, in timezone
 pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Africa/Johannesburg'
```

Notice how it switches from /home/preprodapi/.... to /home/testapi/... in the final item.

But WHY is this happening?

```
(env) [root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25]# deactivate
[root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25]# pwd
/home/preprodapi/API25
[root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25]# . env/bin/activate
(env) [root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25]# pip uninstall pytz
Uninstalling pytz-2017.2:
  Would remove:
    /home/testapi/API25/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytz-2017.2.dist-info/*
    /home/testapi/API25/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytz/*
Proceed (y/n)? n
(env) [root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25]# python
Python 3.5.5 (default, Feb  6 2018, 10:57:32) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytz
>>> print(pytz.timezone('Africa/Johannesburg'))
Africa/Johannesburg
```

For the record I can't find any soft links between the venv's

```
(env) [root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25]# pwd
/home/preprodapi/API25
(env) [root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25]# find env -type l -ls
40549590    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            3 Feb  4 12:54 env/lib64 -> lib
40549592    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           15 Feb  4 12:54 env/bin/python3.5m -> /bin/python3.5m
40549593    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Feb  4 12:54 env/bin/python -> python3.5m
40549594    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Feb  4 12:54 env/bin/python3 -> python3.5m
```

Help please!

P.S note /home/preprodapi/API25.8512 is a cpio copy of /home/preprodapi/API25.  I get the exact same results when I test in the API25.8512 sub-directory

Note #2:  The same does not happen with another venv on this host

```
[root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25.8512]# cd /home/apiuser
[root@ip-172-31-8-200 apiuser]# cd API25
[root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25]# . env/bin/activate
(env) [root@ip-172-31-8-200 API25]# pip uninstall pytz
Uninstalling pytz-2018.9:
  Would remove:
    /home/apiuser/API25/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytz-2018.9.dist-info/*
    /home/apiuser/API25/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytz/*
Proceed (y/n)? n
```

Comment: What's a "cpio copy"? `cpio` is an archiver, not a copy utility.

Comment: Could you upgrade your examples to a [mcve]? Without the means to reproduce the problem, it's impossible to say with confidence what the issue is. E.g. will the same happen if you create a new `venv`, install some packages into it, then copy it?

Comment: What's the value of `pytz.__file__` after you "uninstalled" `pytz` from the current virtual env?

Comment: What's `sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH`? Are you sure you're inside the right venv when the first error happens?

Comment: cpio is indeed a very very capable copy program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your `sys.path` and find the source of anomalies, if any. See [Debugging modifications of sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432910/debugging-modifications-of-sys-path) for a way to track changes to `sys.path` and [Can I zip all the python standard libs and the python still able to import it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969136/can-i-zip-all-the-python-standard-libs-and-the-python-still-able-to-import-it/46970267#46970267) for how it's constructed.

---

`venv` is implemented [via Py3's stock `site.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/site.py#L16-L23):

```
If a file named "pyvenv.cfg" exists one directory above sys.executable,
sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix are set to that directory and
it is also checked for site-packages (sys.base_prefix and
sys.base_exec_prefix will always be the "real" prefixes of the Python
installation). If "pyvenv.cfg" (a bootstrap configuration file) contains
the key "include-system-site-packages" set to anything other than "false"
(case-insensitive), the system-level prefixes will still also be
searched for site-packages; otherwise they won't.
```

When creating a venv, `python` and a number of other files are copied into `<venv>/bin` (`<venv\Scripts` in Windows), and a `pyvenv.cfg` is placed into `<venv>` for `site.py` to find upon Python startup. `activate` prepends `<venv>/bin` to `PATH` so that the local executable is started instead of the system one when you type "`python`".

Ultimately, this results in a `sys.path` that combines system-wide standard library with venv-specific 3rd-party modules. It would look something like this:

```
>>> sys.path
['', '<venv>/bin/python36.zip', <system Python platlib>, <system Python purelib>, '<venv>', '<venv>/lib/site-packages']
```

---

So, normally, there shouldn't be folders from another venv in `sys.path` resulting directly from venv logic. They may result from PYTHONPATH, or from some .pth files, or even from your own code. The above diagnostics should show where they come from.

Comment: It appears that the solution is when one clones a Python application, exclude the venv, re-create it, and re-install those packages from a pip freeze > requirements file from the source.  I don't have time to test this properly right now but it makes complete sense based on my findings so I'm awarding the solution.